# Android API level 21 backward compatibility? (Since the new update of the SDK came out)

Tags: android, xml, build, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have a problem with the API Level 21. I want to use the Material Design and still be able to run the application on lower API levels like 18 (Android 4.3.1). But I always get that error:[image]

My manifest SDK looks like that:

[image]

And the build.gradle like that:
[image]

Hope this is enougth information to get some help, I really need it :(

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in doc :
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

**Note: The material theme is only available in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above**

This means that you have to use the *values-v21* folder for your Material Theme.

However you can use the **v7 Support Libraries** to provide themes with material design styles for some widgets.
This is an example, using the AppCompat Theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>
```

More info here:
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: I have the same problem. I have added I added android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to my build path but I still get the same error as Uchiha. Any ideas?

Comment: @user754730 it is not an issue. It is a normal behaviour. The Theme.Material is only for api 21.

Comment: Hmm okay. How can I use material design on older Android versions then? I haven't found any good tutorials about it yet (Since it's very new I guess...)
I've seen alot of apps use it already and it has material look on my KitKat. How do they do that?

Comment: Read the answer again. Gabriele links to my blog post which shows you how.

Comment: Hi Chris
Now this is embarrassing... I've copied an older version of the v7 lib... Sorry! Now it works...